# Gru(LSTM) model about image compression

Tags: neural-network, lstm, image-compression

Now I am learning image compression in this way :
 https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/compression/image_encoder
But this pbmodel just like a Black-Box，I cannot know the network structor very well,so anyone who have this model or other image compression(loss) models can contact me ,I really want to learn this model, thank you for everyone!

Comment: Great! Now what is your **question**?

Comment: I have the pb_model but don't have the code ,so I need code to analyse zhe whole netwwork or  a new image comporession model 0.0